# MediaWiki CSS in common.css works for Vector but not for MinervaNeue

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, global, mediawiki

I have an RTL (right-to-left, Hebrew) MediaWiki 1.32.0 website with Vector as desktop theme and MinervaNeue as mobile theme.

In `common.css` I have added the following code to prevent `<pre>` LTR (left-to-right) content from moving to the right edge of the screen as all other content would in this RTL site. I gave this class to generally all `<pre>` tags in the web site.

```
.preLTR {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

The problem is that while `<pre>` content in Vector does go left, `<pre>` content in MinervaNeue **doesn't** (although it seems to be accepted in DOM)<sup>[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNvd5.png)]</sup>:

- Adding `!important`, saving and clearing cache doesn't help.

**What can be the problem?**

<sub>[Related discussion on MediaWiki support desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:V3bmgb9s6ex2gy1x)</sub>

Comment: There seems to be some conflict between `.preLTR` class I created and `.content pre` that comes with MediaWiki - but why would there even be this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the same CSS code to this page `Mediawiki:mobile.css`. This page is specially to add styles for mobile skins.

After saving it, and clear the cache, you will find out that the direction is stable in both desktop, and mobile.

Comment: Sorry, cannot upvote yet (need 3 more points, but should do it soon). Thank you so much.